# What's the probability of a dart landing in an embedded interval?

Tags: probability

Assume that the dart has a point as a tip. It is thrown at a hyperreal (reals+infinitesimals) line [0,1]. Assume further that the dart will always land on the line when thrown, and that there is a uniform probability distribution.

The probability that the dart will land on a point x is 0, i.e. p(x)=0. This is because the point x is strictly within the interval $[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]$, with $\varepsilon$ as some arbitrarily small non-zero infinitesimal. The probability that the dart will land in the interval $[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]$ is just $\varepsilon$. Since the point x is strictly within this interval, p(x)<$\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon$. So p(x)=0, since only 0 is smaller than all infinitesimals, without violating the probability axioms.

Imagine another interval $[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$. What is the probability that the dart will land in this interval? Since this interval is strictly within $[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}]$, p($[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$)<$\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon$. Following the previous reasoning for p(x), p($[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$)=0, since 0 is the only number that's smaller than all infinitesimals without violating the probability axioms. Or is p($[x-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$)=$\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$? If so, then that means that if p($\cdot$)<$\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon$, it doesn't mean that p($\cdot$)=0. So p(x) is not necessarily 0. Where did I go wrong in my reasoning? As far as I can tell, my reasoning will still work if it is a real number line, and $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrarily small nonzero real finite number.

Comment: I would have thought you are saying  $p([x-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x+\frac{\varepsilon}{4}])=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ so  $p([x]) \le \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$  for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and thus $p([x]) =0$.  Incidentally, I do not quite see how you are planning to formalise a uniform distribution over the hyperreals

Answer (score 0):

@Henry Let $I$ be the set of all nonzero infinitesimals. Assume that p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) = $\varepsilon_0$, for some $\varepsilon_0$ $\in$ $I$. So p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) $\in$ $I$. But because the interval $[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$ is strictly in the interval $[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}]$, p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) < $\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon$ $\in$ $I$. So p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) $\neq$ $\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon$ $\in$ $I$, and thus p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) $\notin$ $I$. But this contradicts p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) $\in$ $I$. p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) is some infinitesimal, but we just said that p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) < $\varepsilon$, for all $\varepsilon$ $\in$ $I$, which means that it can't be any infinitesimal. So p($[x - \frac{\varepsilon}{4}, x + \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$) can't be $\varepsilon_0$. I might be wrong.